# New type declaring functions?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm familiar with the newtype declaration:

```
newtype MyAge = Age {age :: Int} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

In this instance Age is an Int, however I've come across the code below and I can't understand it:

```
newtype Ages a = Ages {age :: String -> [(a,String)]}
```

This appears to be a function declaration? (takes string, returns list of tuples containing 'a' and string) - is this correct?

N.B I've just realized this is just basic record syntax to declare a function.

**Additionally**, I've tried to implement this type, but I must be doing something wrong:

```
newtype Example a = Example {ex :: Int -> Int}

myexample = Example {ex = (\x -> x + 1)}
```

This compiles, however I don't understand why as I haven't passed the 'a' parameter?

Comment: Don't add new questions to an existing post. That said, `Example a` is an example of the use of a [phantom type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type).

Answer (score 5):

> This appears to be a function declaration?

Yes. Specifically, `String -> [(a,String)]` is a function type. A `newtype` declaration is analogous to a simple wrapper around any given type. There's no restriction that says you can't make it based on a function type, and it works in exactly the same way.

Also remember that you can *always* replace `newtype` with `data`; in this case, thinking about the resulting type as a record type that has a field that is a function might be helpful; `newtype` is just a special, optimized case.

---

One other thing to mention is that your two lines also differ in that the second one is parametrized over `a`. This can of course be used with regular types:

```
newtype MyWrapper a = MyWrapper a
```

or a function type can be `newtype`-d without parametrisation

```
newtype MyFunction = MyFunction (Float -> Float)
```

You can also write the above using the record syntax that gives you the "getter" function as well.

Comment: How can I change this newtype declaration into a normal function declaration?

Comment: @barbrac Do you mean a function declaration or regular type alias? If the latter, simply use `type`.

Comment: @barbrac this is how the question should look like from the start. Please avoid making edits that substantially change the scope of the Q/A.